# jqplot renders not good in chrome?Chrome Displays jqplot axes with improper alignement and padding

Tags: jsp, charts, jqplot, jqchart

I am using jqplot in my jsp page..successfully integrated bar charts,line charts and etc.now i am facing the problem when i see this charts in chrome,in mozila same chart showing perfect with its alignment of y and x axis label,but when i see same charts in chrome the y axis and x axis alignment and padding looks very odd and very conjusted ...let me give u snippet for this

Mozila browser displays like this

[image]

then why lable of axis looks so clumpsy and very nearby withing axis line in this chrome browser?

[image]

so can anyone please guide me how can i remove this difference in chrome and mozila browser and how can make that chart atleast look decent with proper alignment of axes

Here is the code i tried

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    var line2 = [['1/1/2008', 3.03], ['2/14/2008', 2.30], ['3/7/2008', 3.12], ['4/22/2008', 1.25]];

    var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart7', [line2], { animate: !$.jqplot.use_excanvas,

          axes:{
            xaxis:{
              renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
              tickOptions:{
                  pad:2.5,
                  left:10,
                formatString:'%b&nbsp;',
                angle: - 40,
                fontSize: '7pt'
              }
            },
            yaxis:{
                pad:2.5,
              tickOptions:{
                formatString:'%.2f'
                }
            }
          },
          highlighter: {
            show: true,
            sizeAdjust: 1.5
          },
          cursor: {
              style: 'default',
            show: true,

            followMouse: true,
          },grid: {background: 'white'}
      });
    });
```

Comment: please see my updated question for this

Answer (score 1):

I set up a fiddle example with your code : http://jsfiddle.net/WdLnm/330/ which looks great on my `Chrome` browser.

If it looks OK for you too, you are facing a CSS problem on your web site.

Comment: yes...its looks good in chrome with yr link...then how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Try to simplify (remove non essentials elements) the web page where you are displaying the graph, remove all CSS styles, ...

Comment: its not workig...tried just put only single chart with the necessary js and css for its..but still no change